# How to bind the value using Angularjs from MVC controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting value as a list from **MVC controller**. Now I would like to bind those values in **AngularJS**. Is it possible?. If possible means how to bind those value.

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            var payrollAndCalendar = new PayRollCalender();            
            payrollAndCalendar.MyDailyAttendance = new AttendanceApiController().GetDailyAttendance().ToList();
            payrollAndCalendar.ShiftTiming = new ShiftTimingApiController().GetShiftTiming().ToList();
            payrollAndCalendar.Comments = new ShiftTimingApiController().GetComments().ToList();
            return View(payrollAndCalendar);
}
```

this is my controller.Now I would like to bind this in html page using AngularJS
I had surfed a lot in google. But nothing Works.

Comment: Can you detail more ? What do you mean by MVC controller ? Your backend service ?

Comment: ***[DO You Know how to use Juery in MVC? You can do this same for Agularjs also.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par)***

Comment: I had edited the question with sample. Kindly go throw it and do help. Thanks in Advance